# Ionic Framework: How to make two pictures in each list item with?

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework

How would I create it so each ionic framework list item has two images: one image on the left, and one image on the right? The documentation only supports one image - either right or left alligned.

Here is how to create a right alligned one:

```
<div class="list">
<a class="item item-thumbnail-right" href="#">
  <img src="img/image1.jpg">
  <h2>First Vote</h2>
  <p>Question???</p>
</a>
</div>
```

But I need it so there each item has 2 thumbnails.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ionic grid system for your use case :

Visualize each list item as a row and divide it into three columns. For e.g., if i divide them in 25-50-20 ratio, it'll look like :

```
    <div class="list">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-25">
                <img src="img/image1.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col col-50">Your text</div>
            <div class="col col-25">
                <img src="img/image12.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```